# SharePoint and several Active Directory sources(solved)

Tags: active-directory, import

I have either a SharePoint AD sync problem or AD problem.

I have mapped several AD sources to be imported into SharePoint:

- SP-domain AD 1
- AD 2 - > groups to be imported into SC 2
- AD 3 - > groups to be imported into SC 3
- AD 4 - > groups to be imported into SC 4

When I create a group in AD 2, I want that AD group to be in SharePoint's "owner" group. However it doesn't show up.

The AD groups are global security groups and not empty. The users can be found in SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

SharePoint People Picker works directly environments like above.
To be more specific if forests/domains are 2-Way trusted.

So if you have **One-way:outgoing** trusts like my case you have to configure People Picker separately.

**This command on EVERY WFE server!**

```
stsadm –o setapppassword –password <password>
```

- Value of password could be any string, and it is used as the key to encrypt the password wich would be provided with user LDAP guery access account of XX forest/domain.

---

**This command on ONE WFE server!**

```
**stsadm -o setproperty -url http://<server:port> -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:contoso.corp.com;domain:bar.contoso.corp.com", <LoginName>, <Password>**
```

Reference articles:
[link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460.aspx)
[link text](http://www.marc-antho-etc.net/blog/post/2009/07/24/SharePoint-People-Picker-and-Active-Directory-Part-2.aspx)
[link text](http://www.marc-antho-etc.net/blog/post/2009/05/13/SharePoint-People-Picker-and-Active-Directory-Part-1.aspx)